# How to determine if a file can be written using C++

Tags: c++, file, boost

In C++ how can I determine if the program has either read-only access or read-write access to a file? I searched the boost filesystem library but I have yet to find something to help me. Right now I thinking of opening the file, trying to write inside and check for error, but that doesn't seem a very appropriate way of doing this.

Any clue?

EDIT : it would need to be cross platform

Comment: I believe your method is the recommended method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end of the day, the only way to test if you can write data to a file on a modern OS is to actually try to write it. Lots of things could have happened to the file between tests for permission and the actual write.

Comment: I'm fairly new to boost::filesystem, but why not use file_status::permissions?

Answer (score 5):

The system call, which most runtime libraries fully support, is

```
#include <unistd.h>

if (0 == access (char *pathname, int mode))
    // permission is granted
```

where *mode* is `F_OK` to test existence of file, or a mask consisting of the bitwise OR of one or  more of `R_OK`, `W_OK`, and `X_OK`.

Comment: According to the BSD system calls manual, the access() function is a potential security hole and should never be used.  The Linux man pages note the security risk as well but do not state that the function should not be used.

Comment: It's not a system call, and is only supported on POSIX systems.

Comment: Simple and straightforward, I like that! However, it need to be cross platform so I can't use unistd.h ...